# Creating a group of paper-checkbox (using iron-selector?)

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

My goal is to group a set of `paper-checkbox`.

For `paper-ratio-button`, I am doing:

```
<paper-radio-group selected="foo">
  <paper-radio-button name="foo">Foo</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="bar">Bar</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

For `paper-checkbox`, I would have expected to use `iron-selector`:

```
<iron-selector attr-for-selected="name" selected="foo">
  <paper-checkbox name="foo">Foo</paper-checkbox>
  <paper-checkbox name="bar">Bar</paper-checkbox>
</iron-selector>
```

But this does not work, the checkbox with `name=foo` is not selected

Answer (score 4):

I got it working, I was missing `selected-attribute="checked"`:

```
<iron-selector attr-for-selected="name" selected="foo" selected-attribute="checked">
  <paper-checkbox name="foo">Foo</paper-checkbox>
  <paper-checkbox name="bar">Bar</paper-checkbox>
</iron-selector>
```

To allow multiple selection, use `<iron-selector attr-for-selected="name" multi selected-values='["foo","bar"]' selected-attribute="checked">`

Answer (score -1):

You have to write your own little element. It's not that hard.. just something to start with:

parent

```
<my-el selected="foo">
  <paper-checkbox name="foo"></paper-checkbox>
  <paper-checkbox name="bar"></paper-checkbox>
  <paper-checkbox name="foobar"></paper-checkbox>
</my-el>
```

my-el

```
<dom-module id="my-el">
  <template>
    <slot></slot>
  </template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-el',

        properties: {
            selected: {
                type: String,
                observer: "_selectCheckboxes"
            }
        },

        _selectCheckboxes() {
            var checkboxes = this.$.slotted.getDistributedNodes();
            this.reset(checkboxes);
            for (var i = 0; i = checkboxes.length; i++) {
                var obj = checkboxes[i];

                if(obj.getAttribute("name") == value) {
                    obj.checked = true;
                }
            }
        },

        reset: function(obj) {
            for (var i = 0; i = obj.length; i++) {
                obj[i].checked = false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
</script>    

</dom-module>
```

I hope that this will help you. Off course that you have to implement a little bit more logic to make it work. If you have more questions about it just ask, and i can edit my answer.

A little explanation: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade

**By the way**: I assume you are using Polymer version >= 1.7.0. For older versions you have to use `<content>` element instead of `<slot>` and different selector

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using 2.0 preview.

Comment: On Polymer < 1.0, I was using a core-selector, and it was very straightforward: https://github.com/steren/steren.github.com/blob/master/steren-works.html#L85

Comment: @Steren but still.. checkboxes are used for multiple selections and not only one.. if you want to select only one option, then you should use radio-button

Comment: For mutiple selections, I use: `<iron-selector attr-for-selected="name" multi selected-values='["foo","bar"]' selected-attribute="checked">`

Comment: @Steren Cool, nice to know that